# params on remotefunction is not working grails 2.3.4

Tags: javascript, ajax, grails

I am using grails 2.3.4 and according to grails docs there is both `<g:remoteFunction>` and `${remoteFunction}`.I am trying to send values from params to the controller but it is returning null value please help the code is :
The gsp page code is :

```
<div id="test"></div>
    <input type="text" name="myname" id="myname">
<input type="button" name="view" value="view" onclick="myFunction()">
```

and the javascript function is:

```
function myFunction(){

        var name=$("#myname").val();        
        <g:remoteFunction controller="test" action="testreport" update="test" params="{n:name}"></g:remoteFunction>

    }
```

and the controller code is

```
def testreport(){
        println"test"
println "params value is "+params.n
        println params
    }
```

and the output is :

```
test
params value is null
[action:testreport, format:null, controller:test]
```

Answer (score 3):

I have used g:remoteFunction in many ways, within gsp - you could use:

```
    <button id=boxbtn onclick="<g:remoteFunction controller="Controller"   
action="action"   params="${[id:inputid, sortby:sortby, order:order, s:s,
  userchoice:'yes', viewtype:'na', offset:offset, max:max]}" update="siteContent"  />">
```

**UPDATE**
try using this as your myFunction instead of what you had above

```
function myFunction(){
        var name = document.getElementById('myname');        
        <g:remoteFunction controller="test" action="testreport" update="test" params="${[n:name]}"></g:remoteFunction>

    }
```

Comment: this also shows null.test
params value is null
[action:testreport, format:null, controller:test]

Comment: that is because it is not the remote function but your java script passing values to it .....

Answer (score 1):

You're messing things up.  is executed on the server side when the view gets rendered. Your Javascript variable `name` will have a value when the browser executes your Javascript on the client side. There is a typo in your code. Instead of

```
<g:remoteFunction controller="test" action="testreport" update="test" params="{n:name}"></g:remoteFunction>
```

use

```
<g:remoteFunction controller="test" action="testreport" update="test" params='\'n=\' + name'></g:remoteFunction>
```

and if you have more than one param to submit use

```
<g:remoteFunction controller="test" action="testreport" update="test" params='\'n=\' + name&paramName=\' + varName\''></g:remoteFunction>
```

Comment: For passing one parameter, the above solution works fine. What if we want to pass second parameter from another <g:select> defined similarly: var name=$("#myname2").val(); . How will the params: change then?

Comment: i have tried this but it is showing following error:
org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.taglib.exceptions.GrailsTagException Attribute value must be quoted (controller="test" action="testreport" update="test" params='\'n=\'+name').